# Atom-Editor package remote-ftp connection issue

Tags: atom-editor

I just downloaded Atom-Editor and Installed package remote-ftp but not able to connect to my server. 
Here is the .ftpconfig  flie

```
{
"protocol": "ftp",
"host": "www.xxx.com",
"port": 21,
"user": "xxx",
"pass": "xxx",
"promptForPass": false,
"secure": false,
"secureOptions": null,
"connTimeout": 10000,
"pasvTimeout": 10000,
"keepalive": 10000,
"watch":[],
"watchTimeout":500
}
```

Its just trying to connect "Remote FTP: Connecting.." and after 10-15 seconds "Remote FTP: Connection Closed".